# Orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $\{\phi_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space and $\alpha_n$ are scalars then $\| \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k\phi_k\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^m |\alpha_k|^2$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

This was in a proof I was reading, but I didn't see how it was true. Any suggestions for showing this? Maybe a Holder's inequality argument?

Comment: I rolled the edit back because the info you deleted is good to have in your question. It's encouraged for you to include the context of the problem and thoughts you had on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows straight from linearity and orthonormality: $$\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\alpha_k\phi_k\right\|^2=\left\langle \sum\limits_{k=1}^m\alpha_k\phi_k, \sum\limits_{j=1}^m\alpha_j\phi_j\right\rangle =\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^m\alpha_k\bar{\alpha}_j\langle \phi_k,\phi_j \rangle=\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^m\alpha_k\bar{\alpha}_j\delta_{jk}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^m |\alpha_k|^2$$